# How to use “port install” without upgrading dependencies?

Tags: macos, installation, macports

As more-and-more ports depend on a great deal of other ports and those ports are frequently upgraded installation of a single port can take long hours due to unnecessary upgrades of dependencies.

Can I somehow specify for macports that I do not want to upgrade my existing dependent ports when I install a new port?

something like

```
sudo port install --no-deps portname  #  but this does not work
```

I have checked macports guide, have tried to google it up, the most similar question I have found is [Debian: How to use “apt-get install” without upgrading dependencies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/316412/debian-how-to-use-apt-get-install-without-upgrading-dependencies?lq=1) I have tried the option in the answer there but it does not work for macports.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Consider moving it to AskDifferent

Comment: How do you know the upgrades are unnecessary? Also for many setups you download a binaries and not have to build

Comment: @Mark In case of large libraries such as opencv or boost the chances are that the newest features are not used by a program. But if I could avoid building each and every port that would be great! Can you tell how can I specify that for "port install"?

Comment: @gaige I agree with you. However, I have looked at 10 of the 564 questions here tagged with macports and only 1 out of them could be considered as "programming question". I was surprised but figured I could fit here if so many other similar questions do. **AskDifferent was a great idea, thanks, I will ask it there too in some other form!**

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs it should do by default see macports.conf - also try  a -b parameter to port

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I've found parameter -n to port and it worked nicely (also, together with -b)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cudos, Mark!

I have looked at port options in `man port` and I have found the following surprisingly simple way:

```
-n       don't upgrade dependencies (affects upgrade and install) 

-b       binary-only mode (build and install from binary archives, ignore
         source, abort if no archive available)
```

so `port -bn install someport` can be tried as the quickest way.

Comment: by the way, consider upgrading to `brew`. For me it works a lot better.